# Trying to brute force Ceasar Cipher, cannot get correct characters to appear

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to get my code to wrap around the alphabet, for example Z + 1 should = A. Instead I am getting junk values of non-English characters. How do I make my code only use the alphabet and not the junk characters?

```
enc = "Lbh ner havdhr va gur jbeyq n sevraq yvxr ab bgure Vg vf fb nznmvat gung jr unir fb zhpu va pbzzba fb lbhe unccvarff vf nyfb zvar"
blankList = [] #create the empty list
count = -30
while count < 40: #if less than 40 continue
    dec = ''  #empty string  
    for i in enc: #iterarte through
        a = ord(i)  #convert
        b = a + count # create var to store it 
        dec += chr(b) #to letter
    count += 1 #increment count 
    blankList.append(dec)

for i in blankList: #go through blank list
    print i #prints each on own line
```

Comment: By testing each character after adding or subtracting a number. You know how the Caesar Cipher works?

Comment: Can you provide the current output and fix indentations. That "while count" <- everything is falling out.. if it matters at all

Comment: Two problems here.  First, a Ceasar Cipher is generally case insensitive.  You need to upper or lower then entire string.  That leading 'L' is a problem.

Have you tried printing out ord('a') and ord('z') and seeing what they are?  This might be useful in seeing how to wrap around from ord('z') + 1 to ord('a')

Comment: Why did you change your top question?  StackOverflow is about recording questions and answers to help others with the same problem.  You have now changed it in an attempt to get help with your latest problem.  This makes your question worth much less to everyone else.  Also it is very helpful to show before and after in code.  i.e. Don't remove your original problem block and add update blocks as kind of a running commentary.  This is about asking and giving back.  Being a good citizen to help others grow too.

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving "junk" characters, because you are asking `chr()` to convert a value to a character that is not a normally printed character.  This is because you are not wrapping around the edges of the alphabet correctly.

A simple way to see this is to run:

```
for i in range(255):
    print(i, chr(i))
```

This prints the ASCII code and ASCII character.  Those listed with `\x` prefix are ASCII value in hexadecimal, because the character isn't normally printed.  Many ASCII characters are used for control codes and other things for terminals.

Once you fix the edge wrapping of values past `ord('z')` then you should get a handle of this.  You also only need to try 25 variations, because there are only 25 characters in the alphabet that can be the other values for this string.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, but I am a very novice level programmer and am not sure how to implement that back into my code? Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should use `for count in range(26)` rather than a while loop, and then after `b = a + count`, you want `if b > ord('z') : b -= 26` to wrap back to the beginning of the alphabet.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin and Joe!

Comment: 13:You-are-unique-in-the-world-a-friend-like-no-other-ct-is-so-amazing-that-we-have-so-much-in-common-so-your-happiness-is-also-mine.   This is the output I am getting, why do the "- "show up and why does it say "ct," after other, and not "It."

Comment: You are shifting the space character.  Excule shifts if it equals the value of `ord(' ')`.